# Facebook Style "Like" button without postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would one go about creating a facebook-style "Like" button in C# ASP.NET without doing a postback? Are there any code examples or tutorials that you know of? I assume that would have to use asynchronous javascript. (this is a tough one to search for due to the Facebook keyword!)

This would have to work with .NET 2.o framework, SQL Server 2005 and VS 2005.

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: I suppose I could have used the "star favorite question" and the "accept answer" check icon as an example right here on this page.

I'll check out the info jquery too.

Please feel free to add links to any superb "hello world" tutorials on this topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technology you are looking for is AJAX. It is a fancy way to use JavaScript (specifically the httprequest object) and the HTML DOM to asynchronously do things on web pages.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050526.htm) specific to ASP.NET. It was written for .NET 1.1, but the principles are basically the same.

Suggestion: I really prefer the [JQUERY AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) implementation to the controls that ASP.NET has built in, even when working on ASPX pages. It just seems a lot more lightweight and has less magic going on behind the scenes.

Comment: (To promote my own answer...) Isn't the server side of this best implemented as a web service when using ASP.NET?

Comment: Usually yes. I just wanted to get him on the right track. I think the tutorials I mentioned cover that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking here but maybe an ASP.NET Web Service would be what you're looking for?

Here are a few links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx
- https://web.archive.org/web/20210304124019/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062602-1.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/aspwebsvr.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, you need to incorporate AJAX functionality and web services in your page for this to happen. One option is to use [Page Methods](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services). Another option is to write wcf services that directly emit JSON[via the [ScriptService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx) attribute] and use the callback mechanism to call these services, and handle their response in the success method to update the UI accordingly. Take a look at [how to create wcf sercvices for emitting json.](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2010/02/01/Creating-a-WCF-Service-for-JSON.aspx)