# Facebook like button

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

Can anyone tell how can remove unlike functionality from facebook like button?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410519/facebook-style-like-button-without-postback

Answer (score 2):

Modification of the "Like" button is not allowed...

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

*"By using the Like Button, you agree to the general guidelines and terms found here. You also agree that you will not modify the Like Button in any way beyond the customization options provided on this page."*

Answer (score -1):

I thought unlike was added by 3rd party apps anyway. The only way I can think of doing it is using jquery to find the unlike elements on the page after everything has loaded and then remove them.